# How can I pass a 2D array from one form to another?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to pass a 2D dimensional array called cell from one form (form_spreadsheet) to another form (ChartMenu) but I am getting the error: 'Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Cell[*,*] is less accessible than method 'ChartMenu.ChartMenu(Cell[*,*])'.

Both forms are set as public and I have tried to pass the array through the second form's(ChartMenu) constructor.

```
    public partial class form_spreadsheet : Form
    {
    Cell[,] cell = new Cell[27, 27];
    bool sheetActive = false;

    public form_spreadsheet()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void btn_charts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChartMenu chartMenu = new ChartMenu(cell);
        chartMenu.Show();
    }

    public partial class ChartMenu : Form
    {
    public ChartMenu(Cell[,] cell)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cmbo_palette.Items.Add("Berry");
        cmbo_palette.Items.Add("Chocolate");
        cmbo_palette.Items.Add("Fire");
        cmbo_palette.Items.Add("SeaGreen");

        List<string> selectedRange = new List<string>();
        int[] cellValues;

        selectedRange = Formulas.GetCellRange(txt_selectedRange.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRange.Count; i++)
        {
            //cellValues[i] = 
        }
    }
    }
```

I want the 2D array to pass from one form to another.

Comment: Well, `ChartMenu` is `public`.  Is `Cell` also `public`?  The error is telling you that it's not.  So consuming code that sees `ChartMenu` but can't see `Cell` wouldn't be able to understand the method signature.

Comment: Please show us how your `Cell` class is defined. Somewhere, you have `class Cell...`. Is it `public class Cell`, `private class Cell`, or what? This is distinct from your private field `Cell[,] cell`.

Comment: Hi, this was in fact the problem. I've changed the Cell class to public and it is now functioning. Rookie mistake from my side but sometimes all you need a second pair of eyes so I thank you both for your comments! If any of you would like to post your comment as the answer I will mark it as the correct answer.